# What is the point of Auto-Implemented Properties? ie {get; set;} syntax

Tags: properties

I realize what the {get; set;} syntax is doing from this link on [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

What I do not understand is what is the point beside confusing the hell out of new C# programmers???

I mean first we get taught the whole point of Properties and Accessors is to prevent clients from having uncontrolled access to the fields within the class.

But isn't this EXACTLY with the auto-implemented property is doing?

I mean you can only use this syntax if you do not implement any logic for the property accessors. In fact you cannot even access the private anonymous backing field that is created by the compiler within the class object itself?

So what is the difference from just declaring a public field called Name in the class??

I see no difference between

```
class Foo
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and this

```
class Foo
{
   public string Name;
}
```

Other then the fact that the auto-implemented property version is longer, more confusing, and made me spent 3 hours trying to understand it and gave me a splitting headache and made me want to write this rant!

Furthermore, it seems to me that the auto-implemented property version actually is less efficient in that the compiler is doing alot more work behind the scenes.  It has to create the private anonymous backing filed, the get and set accessors, and finally call the accessors.  Where the second version simply reads and writes to the public field directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's just for simplification. The compiler will auto-generate the regular implementation.

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

Comment: Not really.  If that was the case then I should be able to access _name but I don't think I can.

Comment: dumb 5 minute rule for editing comments.  I meant if the compiler was doing what you say them I should be able to use _name or this._name in any method within the class, but I cannot.

Comment: All I can see as a reason for using this syntax is to follow an unenforced rule that all fields which can be read or modified within a class must be done using a Property and Accessor.  So why not just enforce it and disallow public fields within a class?

Comment: I Agree with @crbram. Its not a simplification, and it can be confusing that all the info on the internet calls it one. If it were just a simplification, than you would expect to be able to do something like this._name as ctbram suggests. I think the real answer is that it allows for more future flexibility than simply having a public property without having to write as much code to gain that flexibilty. This flexibility is achieved by the fact that the compiler then generates these private variables, meaning client code doesn't actually interact with a public member variable. Both right.